# How to get all between two dates by carbon

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I get two date from user for example :

```
2016-10-01
2016-11-05
```

now I would like to get all dates between these two dates :

```
2016-10-01
2016-10-02
2016-10-03
2016-10-04
...
2016-11-05
```

I think I must use the `carbon` library. but I don't know how can I do !

Comment: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ - look up the `addDay` function and use a `while` loop.

Comment: possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849334/php-carbon-get-all-dates-between-date-range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$from = Carbon::parse('2016-10-01');
$to = Carbon::parse('2016-11-05');
```

With `Carbon`

```
$dates = [];

for($d = $from; $d->lte($to); $d->addDay()) {
    $dates[] = $d->format('Y-m-d');
}

return $dates;
```