# Carbon date from from now() to past 30 days

Tags: arrays, laravel

Hey guys I've been trying to get an array with the past 30 days in laravel. Trying to use Carbon to get the days now and want to get count it back 30 days any idea how i can get that done? Example 19,18,17,16,15,14 etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Carbon, get all dates between date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849334/php-carbon-get-all-dates-between-date-range)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you want, but I believe this is what you are looking for....

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

$dates = [$now->format('M d, Y')];

for($i = 1; $i < 30; $i++) {
  $dates[] = $now->subDays($i)->format('M d, Y');
}

print_r($dates);
```

Let me know if this solves your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question was earlier asked here [link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849334/php-carbon-get-all-dates-between-date-range)

I copied the code from the other answer for reference:

```
$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2018-06-14', '2018-06-20');

// Iterate over the period
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

// Convert the period to an array of dates
$dates = $period->toArray();
```