# Laravel nested select and conditional statement in view blade

Tags: html, laravel-5, eloquent

So I've succeeded to make a calendar display for the current month. This time, I want to show event details for a specific date. I'm not sure how to get the `$event` data where `$event == $date`.

This is the controller. I have event and dates to be used in the view:

```
$event = Event::where("started_at", '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->toDateTimeString())
         ->orderBy("started_at", "asc")
         ->first();
$data["event"] = $event;
$data["month"] = Carbon::now()->month;
$data["dates"] = range('1', date('t'));
return view('event.all', $data);
```

This is the `event.all` view:

```
@foreach($dates as $date)
    <div class="seven-cols">
        <div class="titlehead">
            <h6>{{$date}}</h6>
            <h6 style="color: lightgrey;">{{date("D", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $date))}}</h6>
            <div style=" ">{{$eventdate = date('d',strtotime(@$event->started_at))}}</div>
            @if($event->started_at == $date)
                <div>Test</div>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

What I got for this code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849334/php-carbon-get-all-dates-between-date-range) suggests I would use `CarbonPeriod` (or create a range with a loop if `CarbonPeriod` not available for you) and then collect the events for each date at the same time.

As a good practice, we should avoid keeping too much logic inside the templates and therefore build as much as we can of the content before actually building the template itself.

Using your example, and assuming that you only want to show one event for each day we could have something like this:

(Not tested code though)

```php
$startDate = Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->toDateTimeString();
$endDate = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

// Narrow down the list from the database
$events = Event::whereBetween("started_at", [$startDate, $endDate])
    ->orderBy("started_at")
    ->get();

$data = CarbonPeriod::create(
    $startDate, 
    $endDate
)
->map(function(Carbon $date) {
    $event = $events
       ->where("started_at", $date->toDateTimeString())
        ->first();

    return [
        "date" => $date,
        "event" => $event,
    ];
});

return view('event.all', $data);
```

And in the template:

```html
@foreach($data as $day)
    <div class="seven-cols">
        <div class="titlehead">
            <h6>{{$day["date"]->day}}</h6>
            <h6 style="color: lightgrey;">{{$day["date"]->format("D")}}</h6>
            <div style=" ">{{$day["date"]->format("d")}}</div>
                @if(!is_null($day["event"]))
                    <div>{{$day["event"]->someTextField}}</div>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I hope it helps!