# How to get array of dates between two dates in laravel?

Tags: laravel, date

I want to get dates between two dates in an array. The scenario is the following: I want to get daily sales cash collection and there is one filter of `$fromdate` and `$todate`. So even if I don't get any sales for an specific date I have to show that in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CarbonPeriod for this.

I found something helpful at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50854594/13642447.

Answer (score 0):

Use DatePeriod class to create the range of dates based on months or days

```
<?php


$begin = new DateTime( '2012-08-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '2013-10-31' );

$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

$dates = [];

foreach($daterange as $date){
   $dates[] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
}

var_dump($dates);

?>
```

if you want the range of dates to be by days, say from `2012-08-01` to `2012-08-25` then just change the interval like this `$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');`.